# When I rotate iOS screen, collection view cell is going wrong

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

when I rotate iOS screen without keyboard , it's all fine.
but with keyboard, I rotate screen, all the cell is going wrong.
I don't know how to explain in English, so I uploaded Screenshot.

[This is a Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DjE2.jpg)

Comment: You might be using auto layout. Put proper constraints for Collection view.

Comment: set leading and  trailing constraints

Answer (score 0):

Swift Solution

```
override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    if UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation.isLandscape.boolValue {
        print("Landscape")
        view.endEditing(true)
    } else {
        print("Portrait")
        view.endEditing(true)
    }
}
```

Objective-C Solution

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];

if ( ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] ==  UIDeviceOrientationPortrait)  )
{
   // do something for Portrait mode
  [[self view] endEditing:YES];
}
else if(([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight) || ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft))
{
   // do something for Landscape mode
   [[self view] endEditing:YES];
}
```

Comment: I hope its help you

Answer (score 0):

I used `view.frame.width` for auto-layout constraints.

```
bubbleWidthAnchor = bubbleView.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(view.frame.width/5*3)
```

like this.

Instead of that

```
bubbleWidthAnchor = bubbleView.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width/5*3)
```

and it looks fine.